# Opening a HTML page in firefox browser in side the android application.

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, android-webview

I am having a HTML page which works only on mozilla firfox because of some security issues it does not work over Chrome browser, So How could i embed a mozilla firefox in webview or something I can do to open the page by default in firefox browser in an android application, Below is my code `public class InteractivityPage extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private WebView webView;


Activity activity;
String url = "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/indiannica/interactivity/Interactivity_sample/correct_order/index.html";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.interactivitypage);
    activity = this;

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

}
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

`
The code opening the webview but the page does not work due to Chrome browser therefore Need here Firefox, Please help how to embed Firefox in webview.

Comment: `embed a mozilla firefox in webview` you can't. If you want to open this page in firefox browser, use the regular open intent with target package name of firefox. But beware that not all users (almost nobody actually) is using firefox.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko..already mentioned its not for users, this is the page requirement as it is not supported by Chrome browsers for some security reasons, Therefore I want an firefox in webview, and there is no word like 'can not', Thanks by the way.

Comment: Ok, in theory - everything is possible, you are right. But here is what you will have to do on practice: Compile the WebKit for ARM into native library for Android + implement your own WebView wrap for it. So you likely are going to spend a year doing that. But you are right, it is possible. But not worth to do. So in fact it should be much easier to correct security of the page you want to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally come up with the solution, which open the page in a new Firefox tab, I am working to open this tab in-app browser of the android application.

```
  String url = "https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/indiannica/interactivity/Interactivity_sample/correct_order/index.html";
 Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.setPackage("org.mozilla.firefox");
 try{
     context.startActivity(intent); 
    }
 catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
   { intent.setPackage(null);
     context.startActivity(intent);
   }`
```

Comment: The only working code on the entire website, I have tried so many codes and they all have issues. some will open the app but without navigating to the url which is useless ! .